# How to get diff working like git-diff?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I like the output formatting of `git diff`.  The color and the `+`/`-` representation of changes between lines is easier to read than GNU diff.

I can run `git diff` using `--no-index` flag outside of a git repo and it works fine. However, it appears to be missing the `--exclude` option for excluding files or subdirectories from a recursive `diff`.

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds? (color options and `+`/`-` format of `git diff` and `--exclude` option of GNU diff).

I've experimented with [`colordiff`](http://colordiff.sourceforge.net/), but I still prefer the output format of `git diff`

Comment: To make the blue for additions green, change `newtext` in `/etc/colordiff`. I think git uses green?

Comment: I had never heard of the --no-index flag until now. I've just used it to compare the output from git show to the diff of two files - thanks for that!

Comment: Does `git diff --no-index` still respect Git's "ignore" entries? If so, you could make a wrapper script that temporarily creates a `.gitignore` file, or maybe there's a way to pass ignore entries on the command-line as inline config or something like that.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

This will do the `+/-` rather than `<` and `>`.

```
diff -u file1 file2
```

Since GNU diffutils 3.4 the flag `--color` has been added. Combining both makes the following:

```
diff --color -u file1 file2
```

The flag `--color` also takes an argument, valid options are `never`, `always`, or `auto`. Useful when you want to be more explicit on what needs to be done.

Comment: Cool, this combined with colordiff gets me close enough to what I want.  Guess I need to scroll further down the man page next time...  Thanks!

Comment: A simple way to get colorization with diff -u, is also to pipe the output to tig, the commandline git repo viewer: `diff -u file1 file2 | tig`.

Comment: Install `colordiff` from your apt/yum/pacman repository and use it.

Comment: Needed to enable Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) on Amazon Linux to install `colordiff`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-repositories.html

Comment: Besides `colordiff`, you can also get color with `vim` by defining `cdiff() { diff -u $@ | vim -R -; }`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work on macOS, the BSD diff uses `-u` for a different option.

Comment: Adding `--color=always` will enable colors

Comment: For those who would like to install/upgrade the latest version of diff on Mac, you can run `brew install diffutils`, then reopen the terminal.
-- from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/592067/363687

Answer (score 113):

You can also use `git diff --no-index -- A B` (via [manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html)).

Comment: +1, but sadly this doesn't work if one of the files is a symlink.

Comment: +1 This is very useful as it shows how to make git report where two tracked files  `A` and `B` differ in comparison with *each other* instead of where each file has been modified relative to their last respective revision.

Comment: @EmilLundberg: works for me with symlinks in git 1.9.1 on Linux. I do not know whether earlier versions are broken.

Comment: `git diff --no-index` is great, but as the OP pointed out, it lacks the `--exclude` flag, so it's often of very limited usefulness.

Answer (score 27):

1. Install [colordiff](http://www.colordiff.org/).
2. Update your ~/.colordiffrc (copying /etc/colordiffrc first, if necessary):

   ```
   # be more git-like:
   plain=off
   newtext=darkgreen
   oldtext=darkred
   diffstuff=darkcyan
   ```
3. Use `colordiff -u file1 file2` for two files or `colordiff -ruN path1 path2` for recursively comparing paths.

It's not exactly the same, but it's very close.

Comment: As of Ubuntu Jammy, /etc/colordiffrc includes that setup by default.

Answer (score 20):

This is what I suggest and it's pretty close

```
diff -u FILE1 FILE2 | colordiff | less -R
```

- `colordiff`: You'll have to install this

  - `brew install colordiff` on my Mac.
  - `port install colordiff` on some Macs.
  - `sudo apt-get install colordiff` on Debian or Ubuntu
  - For other platforms, download the  source from [the main page](http://www.colordiff.org/) or [GitHub](https://github.com/daveewart/colordiff) and follow [the installation instructions](https://github.com/daveewart/colordiff/blob/current/INSTALL)
- `-R`: this tells Less to show colors instead of the raw codes.

I ultimately used `-w` because I didn't want to see whitespace diffs.

```
diff -w -u FILE1 FILE2 | colordiff | less -R
```

Edit: As suggested by @Ciprian Tomoiaga in the comment, you can make this a function and put it in your `~/.bashrc` file too.

```
function gdiff () { diff -u $@ | colordiff | less -R; }
```

Comment: To have a single bash function for this add to the .bashrc: `function gdiff () { diff -u $@ | colordiff | less -R; } `

Answer (score 8):

GNU `diff` has a `--color` option since version 3.4 in late 2016 according to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338960/241335) on the Unix SE. That alongside `-u` should be enough to mimic the output of `git diff`:

`diff -u --color=always file1 file2 | less -r`

`--color` must be `always` when used in a pipe, `auto` will turn off color in pipes.

I've only tried this with Git Bash on Windows, where `less -R` would only color the first line of a hunk. `less -r` fixed it for me in that case.

Answer (score 4):

Using only `bash`, `diff`, `tput`, and `less`, we can closely approximate the output of `git diff`.  There will be some notable differences, though, due to the short-sightedness of the `diff` programmers.

Put the following Bash function definition in some file that gets sourced automatically by your user account, and you'll be able to access the function from the command line:

```
function gdiff()
{
    local REG=`tput op`
    local GRP=`tput setaf 6`
    local ADD=`tput setaf 2`
    local REM=`tput setaf 1`

    local NL=$'\n'
    local GRP_LABEL="${GRP}@@ %df,%dn +%dF,%dN @@${REG}"

    local UNCH_GRP_FMT=''

    [[ "${1}" == '@full' ]] && {

        UNCH_GRP_FMT="${GRP_LABEL}${NL}%="
        shift
    }

    diff \
        --new-line-format="${ADD}+%L${REG}" \
        --old-line-format="${REM}-%L${REG}" \
        --unchanged-line-format=" %L${REG}" \
        --new-group-format="${GRP_LABEL}${NL}%>" \
        --old-group-format="${GRP_LABEL}${NL}%<" \
        --changed-group-format="${GRP_LABEL}${NL}%<%>" \
        --unchanged-group-format="${UNCH_GRP_FMT}" \
            "${@}" | less -FXR
}
```

This function works as follows:

1. Ultimately, `diff` gets invoked with various formatting options to specify how changes within the files will be displayed.
2. `tput` is used to insert ANSI color codes into those formatting options.  Note that when using non-ANSI terminals, you may have to replace `tput setaf` with `tput setf`.
3. The output of `diff` is piped into `less`.  `-R` allows ANSI colors to be preserved.  `-X` prevents `less` from clearing the screen upon exiting.  `-F` prevents `less` from operating as a pager if the output fits within one screen.
4. If the first parameter is `@full`, the function will display all unchanged lines in addition to added and removed lines.

Note the following differences between this approach and `git diff`:

1. `git diff` reports three lines of context surrounding each change.  Unfortunately, `diff` seems to complain and exit if you want to specify the number of context lines while also simultaneously specifying formatting options.  (At least it does in Mac OS X Yosemite).  Thanks `diff` programmers.  Therefore, you can either request no lines of context surrounding each change, which is the default behavior, or you can request that all unchanged lines within the file are also reported, by specifying `@full` as the first parameter.
2. Because the lines of context are different from `git diff`, the line numbers reported by this function will also vary from those reported by `git diff`.
3. You may see the presence of single-line changes reported, which is the correct behavior, but annoying when your changed file contains the insertion of single empty lines.  I think `git diff` deals with this better, via its lines of context.  You could try passing different options to `diff` to better deal with whitespace, if you prefer.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks for sharing. One thing I noticed, is that by piping to `less`, the return status code from `diff` is not maintained. Not a big deal, for my use I just removed that bit.

Answer (score 4):

Place this in your rc file, most commonly it would be either `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` :

`diff() { git diff --no-index "$1" "$2" | colordiff; }`

requirements : `git` and `colordiff` should have been installed.

usage : `diff file1 file2`

Answer (score 3):

Since [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) has nice colorizing, I've tested if that works with `diff` too and surprisingly it worked really well out of the box.

`$ diff file1 file2 | bat` or `$ diff -u file1 file2 | bat`

So I suppose you could make a function like this below to be more efficient:

```sh
function bdiff () { diff -u $@ | bat;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`colordiff`](http://www.colordiff.org/):

```
sudo apt-get install colordiff
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `colordiff` or `git diff`, you can get color by `vim`.

```
cdiff() { diff -u $@ | vim -R -; }
```

or simply

```
cdiff() { diff -u $@ | view -; }
```

Comment: This may be the best answer for those not using Linux (or GNU utilities)...

Answer (score 1):

Tested in debian 9
`diff -u --color=always file1 file2`

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to do it from outside the repository so git knows to diff between files. eg. a shell function something like:

```
gdiff() {
    (
        dir=`pwd`
        cd ./$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)/..
        git diff  $dir/$1 $dir/$2
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [colordiff](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/colordiff.1.html):

**Installation:**

```
sudo apt-get install colordiff
```

**Usage:**

```
colordiff -u file_one file_two
```

Gives exactly same difference as shown by `git diff`.

Answer (score 0):

add

> alias diff="git diff --no-index --"

to ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc

This uses git diff to do ordinary diff between two files

Answer (score -2):

I think the config setting :

```
[color]
     ui = true
```

combined with "diff" command's `--relative=<path>` option would do what you wanted. Did you try ?

Comment: This is for the diff in `git`. He was asking for the  `diff` program options