# Git: How to diff two different files in different commits?

Tags: git, diff, commit

I have a repository where a number of files have been renamed from .html to .php and further edited in a number of commits since my last pull.  Using `git diff` to shows all the `html` contents removed and all the `php` content added.  Is there a neat way to have `git diff` detect the renames (something like `git log --follow` does), or directly compare different filenames across different commits (something like the solution in [Git: How to diff two different files in different branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131135/git-how-to-diff-two-different-files-in-different-branches) , but for commits)?

Comment: Did you use `git mv` when changing the files originally?

Comment: git diff commit1:file1_path commit2:file2_path

Comment: This does the trick, thanks, please convert to an answer so I can accept.  (It is at the individual file level, unfortunately, but I can do what needs to be done with it for now.)

Comment: @dave: not actually sure - someone else moved the files.

Comment: @dave: that does not actually matter. Git normally *detects* renames (rather than recording them) by doing tree comparisons. That, however, requires that you diff two complete trees, not two specific files within the tree.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can always compare 2 files in 2 different commits:

```
git diff commit1:file1_path commit2:file2_path
```

Comment: Answers with just code get flagged as 'Low Quality Posts', try explaining your answer a little to avoid it being deleted.

Comment: @ElpieKay provided this answer as a comment on my question a year back - tagging him here to provide it as an answer.  If I don't get a response from him in a week, Eugene, ping me here and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @SteveKroon It would be already 3 weeks tomorrow since the time of your comment. I appreciate ElpieKay input, he really added good commented, but looks like he is not available. If you like, feel free to accept my answer/

Answer (score 7):

As said previously, the format needed is:

```
$ git diff commit1:file1_path commit2:file2_path
```

But there are a couple gotchas:

```
XXX$ git diff file1_path commit2:file2_path
```

This will not work, even if file1_path is in `HEAD`; if you want to specify a commit for one file you must specify it for both. This will attempt to interpret "commit2:file2_path" as a file path with the first directory it steps into being, e.g., `HEAD^:foo/`. This will rarely exist so it generally gives an informative error message. (Note: @philh says that `git diff commit1:file1_path file2_path` works fine, but I haven't confirmed that myself.)

`file1_path` format: The paths given will be treated as relative to the repository's root. Absolute paths are not permitted, and relative paths must be explicit. For a concrete example; say your directory structure looks like the below, and your working directory is `~/repo/proj`:

```
~/repo
  .git
  proj
    tests
      foo
        bar.sh
    utils
      baz
        quux.sh
```

If you are trying to compare `HEAD^:(...)/bar.sh` to `HEAD:(...)/quux.sh`, the only permissible paths for `bar.sh` are:

- `proj/tests/foo/bar.sh`
- `./tests/foo/bar.sh`

The *explicit* relative path with `./` works, but the more common *implicit* path `tests/foo/bar.sh` will *not* work. That version will sometimes fail *silently* - I think this is based on the format used in the other arguments but I'm not sure. Absolute paths will also not work; `~/repo/proj/tests/foo/bar.sh` and `/home/username/repo/proj/tests/foo/bar.sh` will fail. AFAICT that will never fail silently.

Comment: "if you want to specify a commit for one file you must specify it for both"

Not entirely - it seems that `git diff path1 foo:path2` doesn't work, but `git diff foo:path2 path1` does.

Comment: Huh, I thought I tested that and it failed.