# Diff syntax highlighting in Github Markdown

Tags: github, markdown, syntax-highlighting

I'm writing documents that should explain code in C# using Markdown.

I use the ```` ```csharp ```` to get csharp highlighting.

I sometimes want to highlight something specific in the code using bold or anything.

I know about `<pre>` etc... but it takes away my csharp highlighting.

Best case scenario - some way to highlight code in the ```` ```csharp ```` section.

Next best thing - I can write the code as diff - using + and - to highlight stuff, but how do I tell Github to highlight diff syntax with the red and green backcolor?

Is there a way to use both diff and csharp syntax highlighting?

Comment: If someone else came here looking for `diff` highlighting support in SE, the answer is [no](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286367/is-there-a-language-syntax-highlighting-setting-for-diff).

Comment: [I opened this discussion on the matter](https://github.com/github/linguist/discussions/5758)

Answer (score 460, accepted):

Github's markdown supports diff when formatting code. For example:

````
```diff
public class Hello1
{
   public static void Main()
   {
-      System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
+      System.Console.WriteLine("Rock all night long!");
   }
}
```
````

Output:

[image]

and it should give you [the Diff looks you are looking for](https://gist.github.com/salmedina/ad8bea4f46de97ea132f71b0bca73663#file-markdowndiffexample-md), highlighting in red what has been removed and in green what has been added.

Comment: I tried it in this gist. Hope it helps.
https://gist.github.com/salmedina/ad8bea4f46de97ea132f71b0bca73663#file-markdowndiffexample-md

Comment: Wow! My bad. I was searching for "diff syntax highlighting in stackoverflow code blocks" and was lead here. Yes! it works on github and that's why I was hoping it would work on stackoverflow. Alas, it does not and it appears there is not enough interest in making it work. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272207/add-syntax-highlighting-language-for-diff

Comment: Do you know how to get the right syntax highlighting AND the diff highlighting?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be supported as of now. Here is a cheatsheet of what is supported. https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code. Hope this helps.

Comment: @math2001 have you find anything to do that? both syntax highlighting and diff?

Comment: Unfortunately, no... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405248/syntax-highlighting-combine-diff-and-xxx

Comment: Tip: in order to easily generate these diffs you can do `git diff filename_with_diffs.txt > diffs.md` and then you only need to add the `\`\`\`diff` at the start and a `\`\`\`` at the end in the `diffs.md`file.

Comment: That's a hot ‍ tip. The only thing missing is how to avoid all of the extra junk on top and **just** get the diffs.

Answer (score 30):

Salvador's response is correct, however, I found out that you should add the diff header to the code snippet in order to highlight it:

````
```diff
diff --git a/filea.extension b/fileb.extension
index d28nd309d..b3nu834uj 111111
--- a/filea.extension
+++ b/fileb.extension
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
-oldLine
+newLine
```
````

I hope that helps!

Comment: If someone is looking just for the git format, without the colors... https://stackoverflow.com/a/4857407/3196753

Comment: I couldn't really get this to work. Do you happen to know where I could read more?

Comment: I can't get this to work either. Mayb eI'm doing it wrong?
```diff
diff --git a/filea.js b/fileb.js
index d28nd309d..b3nu834uj 111111
--- a/filea.js
+++ b/fileb.js
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
-export let tada = "hello world"
+export const tada = "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

1. Just add ```` ```diff ```` on start, and ```` ``` ```` on end.
2. Removed line, put a `-` on start
3. Added line, put a `+` on start

The final you will get some like this:

```
-$a = 14;
+$a = 12;

-function myTest()
+function test()
```

[image]

> [Source](https://github.com/forem/forem/issues/2087#issuecomment-1203089191)