# Syntax Highlighting Combine diff and xxx

Tags: github, diff, syntax-highlighting

I've just seen this (old) post, and I was wondering if we could the same thing using GitHub flavoured markdown: Combine the normal syntax highlighting with the `diff` one.

[image: syntax highlighting: diff and normal combined]

I tried a few things, like

````
```python&diff
- import that
+ import this
```

```python
- import that
+ import this
```

```pythondiff
- import that
+ import this
```

```diffpython
- import that
+ import this
```
````

But none of them worked... So, do any of you know how to do this? Or it's not possible?

Comment: [I opened this discussion on the matter](https://github.com/github/linguist/discussions/5758)

Answer (score 15):

The old post you refer to is "[Syntax Highlighted Diffs](https://github.com/blog/1932-syntax-highlighted-diffs)", Dec. 2014

However, nothing in the current [GFM (GitHub Flavored Markdown)](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) suggests this particular combination (of diff and syntax highlighting) is currently supported.

Comment: Has anything changed since you posted your answer in 2016?

Comment: @ShimmyWeitzhandler Not that I know of, and the [2022 discussion](https://github.com/github/linguist/discussions/5758) on this does not leave much room for hopes.