# GitHub text editing

Tags: javascript, github, github-issues

How can I format code to have the following result?

[image]

I know how to highlight js code block, but don't understand how can I highlight diff.
Thank you.

Comment: This feature is exclusively available in version controls and you can access it via the version control itself or your IDE VC tools.

Comment: at least how can I highlight the line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diff syntax highlighting in Github Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883421/diff-syntax-highlighting-in-github-markdown)