# How to compare, with git diff, two remote files which are not in a repository?

Tags: git, ssh, diff

I can compare two remote files with `diff` and `ssh`:

```
diff <(ssh machine1 "sudo cat ${FILE}") <(ssh machine2 "sudo cat ${FILE}")
```

but if I try with `git diff`,

```
git diff --no-index --color-words <(ssh machine1 "sudo cat ${FILE}") <(ssh machine2 "sudo cat ${FILE}")
```

I obtain:

```
error: /dev/fd/14: unsupported file type
fatal: cannot hash /dev/fd/14
```

How can I, with `git diff`, compare two remote files not in a repository ?

== Update ==

This question is not about substituting `git diff` by `diff` and `colordiff`, but about using `git diff --no-index` through `ssh`.

Comment: git diff doesn't seem to work with process substitution, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22706714/10155936), why not just use diff ?

Comment: I prefer to use `git diff`, it has better output formatting.

Comment: You can make `diff` output like `git diff`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4857310/10155936)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since process substitution cannot be used because of a [forgotten patch](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=141347274420939&w=2), the only option (since you want to use `git diff`) is :

```
ssh machine1 "sudo cat ${FILE}" > temp1 
ssh machine2 "sudo cat ${FILE}" > temp2
git diff --no-index temp1 temp2
```

You can achieve the same using `diff` (it maintains formatting and colors similar to `git diff`) which works with process substitution too

```
diff -u --color <(ssh machine1 "sudo cat ${FILE}") <(ssh machine2 "sudo cat ${FILE}")
```

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni `&&` indicates that the second ssh command will run only if the first one completes successfully. However, it is not required in this case and I have edited it. Regarding process substitution, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22706714/10155936) explains it clearly

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> git diff --no-index <(ssh machine1 "sudo cat ${FILE}") <(ssh machine2 "sudo cat ${FILE}")

As found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17194704/1772368).

Comment: Same problem, same error message. I've updated my question.

Comment: I'm looking how to show colorized character differences.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni you are probably looking for `diff -u --color <(ssh machine1 "sudo cat ${FILE}") <(ssh machine2 "sudo cat ${FILE}")`

Comment: I have `diff: unrecognized option --color`, on macOS.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni there are other options too, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8800578/10155936)